# CentOS adding user id

Tags: syntax, centos

I am trying to create a user id in Cent OS, but when I enter the command: `useradd <admin>`, I keep getting the error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

< and > are invalid username characters.

If they were valid you'd have to escape them...

```
useradd \<admin\>
```

...but they're not. Stick with alphanumeric.